# Query nested items containing all words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elastic search that contains simple nested items, defined this way:

```
'index' : 'items',
'body' : {
    'name' : {'type' : 'string'},
    'steps' : {
      'type' : 'nested',
      'text' : {'type' : 'string'},
    }
  }
```

Each step is a line in the object definition. Let's consider I have the four following objects:

```
obj1:
  foo

obj2:
  bar

obj3:
  foo bar

obj4:
  foo
  bar
```

I want to be able to search objects that have a line containing all words in the query. So If I query with 'foo bar', only 'obj3' will appear in the result.

My current query is has follows:

```
'index : 'items',
'body' : {
  'query' : {
  'match' : {
    "steps.text": {
        'query' : 'foo bar',
        'operator' : 'and'
    }
  }
}
```

This query almost works (it filters out obj1 and obj2 as they only contain one of the word) but obj4 still appears.

So is there a way to tell elastic search "at least one step matches all the words" ?

Thanks in advance,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve the issue :)
The query should have been:

```
{
  nested: {
     path: 'steps',
     query: {
       match: {
         text: {
           query: 'foo bar',
           operator: 'AND'
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This way it only finds items where one step contains 'foo' and 'bar'.